# Spring + Liquibase

Tags: spring, liquibase

I've got spring application. And recently added Liquibase bean. It's necessary to run it before all beans, including annotated beans like (@Component, @Service etc.). How can I do it without using depends-on.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The options are the same as in [Spring: Make sure a particular bean gets initialized first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868335/spring-make-sure-a-particular-bean-gets-initialized-first)

Depends-on appears to be the standard pattern, but perhaps using the Liquibase ServletListener would work better in your case?