# How to start H2 db TCP server within Spring Boot application and with flyway

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway, h2db

I use Spring Boot and H2 db with Flyway, and I want to start the H2 db tcp server upon start of my application (written in Spring Boot).

So I have such **application.properties** file.

```
db.port=9090
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:${db.port}/./database/ifin-relax
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
flyway.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:${db.port}/./database/ifin-relax
flyway.table=SCHEMA_VERSION
flyway.user=sa
flyway.password=password
```

And also I have the following configuration class for h2 db server.

```
@Configuration
public class H2DBServerConfiguration {

    @Value("${db.port}")
    private String h2DbPort;

    @Bean
    public Server server() throws SQLException {
        return Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", h2DbPort).start();
    }
}
```

But when I run the application it fails with exception

```
Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource
```

It seems that flyway tries to apply migrations even before H2's TCP server was instantiated. So the question is how to postpone flyway migrations until the DB Server is started?

Comment: I'm not familiar with sprint boot however in your configs the passwords are different: password != prime.

Comment: My bad, edited the password.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas. Do you have any more logs? Maybe turn debug on.

Comment: I already found a solution, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
@Configuration
public class H2ServerConfiguration {

    @Value("${db.port}")
    private String h2TcpPort;

   /**
    * TCP connection to connect with SQL clients to the embedded h2 database.
    *
    * @see Server
    * @throws SQLException if something went wrong during startup the server.
    * @return h2 db Server
    */
    @Bean
    public Server server() throws SQLException {
        return Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", h2TcpPort).start();
    }

    /**
     * @return FlywayMigrationStrategy the strategy for migration.
     */
     @Bean
     @DependsOn("server")
     public FlywayMigrationStrategy flywayMigrationStrategy() {
         return Flyway::migrate;
     }
}
```

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45643148/4687348) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)

Comment: What is the class of this Server

Comment: @StanPeng if you meant package so it's org.h2.tools.Server