# Need to inject property during bean initialization

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have an application consuming REST, and I want to parameterize my API token into the `RestTemplate`. I tried to autowire the bean containing the token, but the bean is still null at the time the `RestTemplate` is created. I think I can do this using `@PostConstruct` somehow, but I can't come up with the code. So I have this:

```
package com.company;
...
import com.company.api.dashboard.config.Credentials;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    DashboardClient client;

    @Autowired
    Credentials credentials;

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplateAS(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
         // here is where I try to use the autowired Credentials class
        return builder.additionalInterceptors(new ASRequestHeaderInterceptor("Authorization", "Bearer " + credentials.getApiToken()), 
                                              new ASRequestHeaderInterceptor("ContentType", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString()),
                                              new LoggingRequestInterceptor())
                .messageConverters(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter())
                .requestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()))
                .build();
    }
    ...
}
```

And here is the `Credentials` bean:

```
package com.company.api.dashboard.config;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("credentials")
public class Credentials {
    private String oauthUser;

    private String oauthPassword;

    private String apiToken;

    public String getOauthUser() {
        return oauthUser;
    }

    public void setOauthUser(String oauthUser) {
        this.oauthUser = oauthUser;
    }

    public String getOauthPassword() {
        return oauthPassword;
    }

    public void setOauthPassword(String oauthPassword) {
        this.oauthPassword = oauthPassword;
    }

    public String getApiToken() {
        return apiToken;
    }

    public void setApiToken(String apiToken) {
        this.apiToken = apiToken;
    }
}
```

If I can't autowire that `apiToken` property, how else can I get it from my application.yml?

Comment: Bean "credentials" shouldn't be null since spring has to resolve it, please, check your spring config.

Comment: It is null. I'm using annotations, and I believe them to be correct.

Comment: Which is the bean that is `null`? Where do you define that bean?

Comment: The `Credentials` bean is null. I define it as shown in my sample.

Comment: @user1660256 can you show how your bean looks like? What annotations do you have on top of your bean? How are you trying to inject the `apiToken`?

Comment: Edited to show `Credentials`

Comment: Okay, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868335/spring-make-sure-a-particular-bean-gets-initialized-first)

Comment: Are you getting a NullPointerException? Post a stack trace also. Everything you have looks good.

Comment: Is it the `Credentials ` bean `null` or the `apiToken`? I've tried to reproduce it, but my config class has been initialized properly.

Comment: Here is the message of the exception: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'main' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'restTemplateAS' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: The credentials bean is null.

Comment: It's shouldn't make much difference. But you can try to inject `Credentials` to the method instead of using `@Autowired`. It's just a wild guess, I will be surprised if this will help

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your main class with `@EnableConfigurationProperties(Credentials.class)` for the properties to be processed. And remove `@Configuration` from the Credetials class.

Comment: Sorry I edited the answer, not sure if you saw it to remove @Configuration from Credentials class too.

Comment: Sorry, the result is the same. Still null.

Comment: Can you update your question with the relevant content of your application.properties or application.yml?