# Autowiring Bean before initialization of another Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring question.

I have two questions related to spring.

If I declare bean like this:

```
@Service
public class Downloader {
    @Bean
    public String bean1() {
        return "bean1";
    }
}
```

Then if other classes will be autowiring "bean1" then method bean1 will be called several times? Or one instance of bean1 will be created and reused?

Second question. How to Autowire some other bean e.g. "bean2" which is String "externalBean" that can be used to construct bean1.

```
@Service
public class Downloader {

    @Autowire
    private String bean2;       

    @Bean
    public String bean1() {
        return "bean1" + this.bean2;
    }
}
```

Currently I'm trying to Autowire this bean2 but it is null during bean1 call. Is there any mechanism that I can specify order of this. I don't know in what context looking for this kind of info in Spring docs.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868335/spring-make-sure-a-particular-bean-gets-initialized-first

Comment: Check out https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes for information on _when_ new beans are instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simple `@Bean` annotation used sets the scope to standard singleton, so there will be only one created. According to the docs if you want to change you need to explicitly add another annotation:

> @Scope changes the bean's scope from singleton to the specified scope

Comment: Thanks. This answers my questions. Dzięki! :)

Comment: @MarcinKapusta the Scope annotation doesn't have anything to do with your question. You don't need it.

Comment: It implicitly explains the @Bean behavior

Answer (score 1):

> Then if other classes will be autowiring "bean1" then method bean1
>   will be called several times? Or one instance of bean1 will be created
>   and reused?

There will be only a single instance of `bean1`, as the implicit scope is *Singleton* (no `@Scope` annotation present).

> Second question. How to Autowire some other bean e.g. "bean2" which is
>   String "externalBean" that can be used to construct bean1.

Being that it is a `String`, a `@Qualifier` **might** be required

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("bean2")
public String bean2() {
    return "bean2";
}
```

Then

```
@Bean
public String bean1(@Qualifier("bean2") final String bean2) {
    return "bean1" + bean2;
}
```

However, this works too.

Spring will be able to look at the *name* of the Bean and compare it to the parameter's one.

```
@Bean
public String bean2() {
    return "bean2";
}
```

and

```
@Bean
public String bean1(final String bean2) {
    return "bean1" + bean2;
}
```

---

The order is calculated automatically by Spring, based on a Bean dependencies.