# Parameter 0 of constructor in ComponentClass required a bean of type 'JpaRepository' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans

```
@Repository
public interface SomeJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, String>
{
   @Modifying
  //....
}
```

my component:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class SomeComponentClass
{
   private final SomeJpaRepository repository;
   private final SomeMapper someMapper;
   private final int property_1;
   private final int property_2;

   public SapRequestQueue(SomeJpaRepository somejpaRepository, SomeMapper someMapper,
                          @Value("${xxx.property_1}") int property_1, @Value("${xxx.property_2}") int property_2)
   {
      this.property_1 = property_1;
      this.property_2 = property_2;
      this.someMapper = someMapper;
      this.somejpaRepository = somejpaRepository;
   }
```

My error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023.04.28 10:01:02.622 [main] ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter:40 - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in path.service.SomeComponentClass required a bean of type 'path.service.repository.SomeJpaRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'path.service.repository.SomeJpaRepository ' in your configuration.

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:61815', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code structure
Module:

- src
- main
- java
- path.toserviceSomeComponentClass
- path.toservice.repository.SomeJpaRepository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try adding

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "path.toservice.repository")
```

to the configuration. If that solves your problem, then probably something is wrong with your packages structure.

Answer (score 0):

In your class "SomeComponentClass", you could try putting the annotation @Autowired above your private repo, and remove it from your constructor.

```java
@Autowired
private final SomeJpaRepository repository;

public Constructor(prop1, prop2, someMapper){
      this.property_1 = prop1;
      this.property_2 = prop2;
      this.someMapper = someMapper;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the order of beans creation, so it is better to create SomeJpaRepository in the context file to avoid similar issues
Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868335/spring-make-sure-a-particular-bean-gets-initialized-first)