# Load Spring bean at the end

Tags: spring

I have 20 beans in my application-context,I want to load a particular bean after all the beans are loaded. Is there a way for this?

Comment: What's your use-case?  This is an odd requirement, perhaps it could be addressed in a more standard way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [depends-on](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-dependson) to force bean initialization order.

For example if `bean1` depends on `bean2` and `bean3`, you can put:

```
<bean id="bean1" class="YourBean" depends-on="bean2,bean3">
```

in your spring context.

Answer (score 0):

As @skaffman said, this is a very strange requirement. Depending on your needs there are better solutions:

- If you just need to start a process when Spring context is initialized, don't use a [@PostConstruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotated method (or an [InitializingBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html)). [ApplicationListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html) is probably what you need.
- If you are worried because you need some beans injected in a @PostConstruct annotated method don't bother: Spring is usually smart enough for resolving such dependencies. If it isn't in your case, maybe you have an overcomplicated bean design.
- If this isn't enough, you can follow @soulcheck instructions. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187899/order-of-spring-bean-initialization) can probably help you in order to get cleaner configuration files.

If this don't help you, please give us some more information on what are you trying to achieve.