# Liquibase and Spring integration

Tags: spring, liquibase

i am trying to integrate Liquibase with Spring (see this http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/spring.html )
currently i am using Liquibase manually, and i wanted to update the DB as part of the init of the application (war)

everything is working well expect the fact that Liquibase Spring Bean is loaded **after** a lot of other beans (e.g **Spring Security beans**).

how can i make sure that Liquibase bean is loaded before all the other beans ? 
consider that currently Liquibase bean have it's own Spring profile.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187899/order-of-spring-bean-initialization

Comment: what if i have multi beans that `implements BeanPostProcessor` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just stumbled across the same problem and solved it with the [@DependsOn](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html) annotation.
It helps spring to resolve dependencies in an order that makes sense and should be fairly self-explanatory.

Example code:

```
@DependsOn("liquibase")
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                // ... 
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively there is the `depends-on` attribute for XML based configuration.